# How to halt a target device with pyocd?

Tags: embedded, stm32, cortex-m, st-link

I try to halt a F746zg core with pyocd via ST-LinkV2. The ST-Link sees the core. But I'm not able to erase and reprogram it until it's halted. Does anyone know what the right command is to do that?

I tried:

```
pyocd reset -l -t 'stm32f746zg'
```

But I get: 
W Invalid coresight component, cidr=0x0 [rom_table]

Comment: Following worked:
pyocd reset -l -t 'stm32f746zg' -O reset_type=hw -O connect_mode='under-reset'

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that the system was not flashable from remote with following command:

```
pyocd flash -e sector -a 0x8000000 -t 'stm32f746zg' -O reset_type=hw -O connect_mode='under-reset' zephyr.elf
```

But the following procedure seems to work for me.

1. Halt the system

```
pyocd reset -l -t 'stm32f746zg' -O reset_type=hw -O connect_mode='under-reset'
```

2. Erase sector and flash

```
pyocd flash -e sector -a 0x8000000 -t 'stm32f746zg' zephyr.elf
```